# Unit Testing- simple stack class

Tags: python, unit-testing, stack

This is my first real attempt at unit testing. This is an area I'm currently focused on improving.

I say this because I would greatly appreciate any and every improvement!

Stack code:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
        self.size = 0 

    def is_empty(self):
         return not self.items

    def get_size(self):
         return self.size

    def pop(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise IndexError, 'Stack Empty'
        else:
            self.size =- 1
            return self.items.pop()

    def push(self, item, *args):
        if isinstance(item, list):
            self._push_list(item)
        else:
            self.items.append(item)
            self.size +=  1

        if args:
            for a in args:
                self.items.append(a)
                self.size +=  1

    def _push_list(self, l):
        for item in l:
            self.items.append(item)
        self.size += len(l)

    def get_stack(self):
        while not self.is_empty():
            return self.pop()

    def peek(self):
        if self.size == 0:
            return None
        else:
            return self.items[self.size - 1]
```

Unit Test Code:

```
import unittest

from extras import Stack


class TestStackMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.s = Stack()
        self.l = [] # a generic list to append to

    def tearDown(self):
        while not self.s.is_empty():
            self.s.pop()

    def test_test(self):
        self.assertEqual(2, (4/2))

    def test_empty_function_with_items_in_stack(self):
        self.s.push(1)
        self.failIf(self.s.is_empty())

    def test_empty_function_on_empty_stack(self):
        self.failUnless(self.s.is_empty())

    def test_pop_function_with_items_in_stack(self):
        temp = 1 
        self.s.push(temp)
        x = self.s.pop()
        self.assertEqual(temp, x)

    def test_pop_function_on_empty_stack(self):
        with self.assertRaises(IndexError) as c :
            self.s.pop()
        self.assertTrue('Stack Empty' in c.exception)

    def test_peek_function_with_items_in_stack(self):
        self.s.push(1)
        self.s.push(2)
        self.assertTrue(self.s.peek() == 2)

    def test_peek_function_on_empty_stack(self):
        self.assertIs(self.s.peek(), None)

    def test_push_function_for_one_item(self):
        self.s.push(10)
        self.assertTrue(self.s.size == 1)

    def test_push_function_on_a_list_arg(self):
        args = [1,2,3,4]
        self.s.push(args)
        self.assertTrue(self.s.size, 4)

    def test_push_function_on_multiple_args(self):
        self.s.push(1,2,3,4)
        self.assertTrue(self.s.size, 4)

    def test_lifo_functionality(self):
        self.s.push(1,2,3,4)
        while not self.s.is_empty():
             self.l.append(self.s.pop())

        self.assertEqual(self.l, [4,3,2,1])



if __name__ == '__main__':
     unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just going to review the unit tests here.

Overall, it looks reasonably good.  I don't have many changes to suggest.

### Drop `test_test`

I think you probably created this to experiment with the testing infrastructure.  It doesn't contribute to testing `Stack`, so it no longer needs to remain.

### The tear-down is unnecessary

The `Stack` should not need its items removing after use, so just drop the `tearDown` method.  In fact, the `setUp` is debatable - it might be as easy to have a local `s = Stack()` in each test, rather than sharing a member.

### Avoid deprecated methods

Replace `failUnless` with `assertTrue`, and `failIf` with `assertFalse`.

### Simplest tests first

This might just be opinion, but I'd start with `test_empty_function_on_empty_stack` before `test_empty_function_with_items_in_stack`, and I'd write `test_pop_function_on_empty_stack` before `test_pop_function_with_items_in_stack`.  One reason is that when I do test-driven development, it's natural to test the empty stack functions before implementing `push`.

### Don't use `assertTrue` for comparison

Here, we don't get much information if the test fails:

```
def test_push_function_for_one_item(self):
    self.s.push(10)
    self.assertTrue(self.s.size == 1)
```

Instead, we want

```
    self.assertEqual(1, self.s.size)
```

### Avoid loops in tests

I'd be more explicit in the final test:

```
def test_lifo_functionality(self):
    self.s.push(1,2,3,4)

    self.assertEqual(4, self.s.pop())
    self.assertEqual(3, self.s.pop())
    self.assertEqual(2, self.s.pop())
    self.assertEqual(1, self.s.pop())
    self.assertTrue(self.s.is_empty())
```

---

## Modified code

```
class TestStackMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.s = Stack()

    def test_empty_function_on_empty_stack(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.s.is_empty())
        self.assertEqual(0, self.s.size)

    def test_empty_function_with_items_in_stack(self):
        self.s.push(1)
        self.assertFalse(self.s.is_empty())

    def test_pop_function_on_empty_stack(self):
        with self.assertRaises(IndexError) as c :
            self.s.pop()
        self.assertTrue('Stack Empty' in c.exception)

    def test_pop_function_with_items_in_stack(self):
        self.s.push(1)
        self.assertEqual(1, self.s.pop())

    def test_peek_function_on_empty_stack(self):
        self.assertIs(self.s.peek(), None)

    def test_peek_function_with_items_in_stack(self):
        self.s.push(1)
        self.s.push(2)
        self.assertEqual(2, self.s.peek())

    def test_push_function_for_one_item(self):
        self.s.push(10)
        self.assertEqual(1, self.s.size)

    def test_push_function_on_a_list_arg(self):
        args = [1,2,3,4]
        self.s.push(args)
        self.assertEqual(4, self.s.size)

    def test_push_function_on_multiple_args(self):
        self.s.push(1,2,3,4)
        self.assertEqual(4, self.s.size)

    def test_lifo_functionality(self):
        self.s.push(1,2,3,4)

        self.assertEqual(4, self.s.pop())
        self.assertEqual(3, self.s.pop())
        self.assertEqual(2, self.s.pop())
        self.assertEqual(1, self.s.pop())
        self.assertTrue(self.s.is_empty())
```